# animateWithDuration completes immediately

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiimageview, core-animation

I know a ton of people have asked the same question, but none of the proposed solutions seem relevant, so I'm asking again:
I have the following block of code:

```
UIImageView *moneyHolder = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:moneyImage];    
if([paymentMethod.viewed intValue] == 0){
            //CGRect targetFrame = CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height/2-3, cell.frame.size.width, targetHeight);
            CGRect targetFrame = moneyHolder.frame;
            targetFrame.origin.y = cell.frame.size.height/2-3;
            NSLog(@"animating");
            [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                                  delay:0
                                options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^{
                                 moneyHolder.frame = targetFrame;
                             } 
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                 NSLog(@"done");
                             }
            ];
        }
```

Which I would THINK should animate my moneyHolder frame. Unfortunately, this seems to happen immediately rather than with a duration of 2 seconds. I can verify this with timestamps from my log:

2012-05-11 03:41:50.102 AgilePoet[5824:15203] animating
2012-05-11 03:41:50.116 AgilePoet[5824:15203] done

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this might be happening? All the other questions on the subject focused on the property not being animatable, but I know that an imageview frame is animate-able. The only thing I can think is that this code is written inside my

```
-tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its good to see that you have a theory on what might be causing the problem. Can you test it by temporarily copy the animation code to somewhere else and see if it behaves as you expect there?

Comment: well I moved the code outside of the willDisplayCell method and it worked... Does anyone know why it would not work from inside willDisplayCell?

Comment: My guess would be that the drawing code for willDisplayCell calls removeAllAnimations on the cell layer, thereby ending your animation prematurely.

Comment: What did your solution look like ?

Comment: Yea second that, post up some code if you can

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To quote the docs:

> frame The frame rectangle, which describes the view’s location and
>   size in its superview’s coordinate system.
>
> Changes to this property can be animated. However, if the transform
>   property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the frame
>   property is undefined and should not be modified. In that case, you
>   can reposition the view using the center property and adjust the size
>   using the bounds property instead.

If you, or some other code, has changed the transformation matrix for the view, changes to the frame property don't work as expected.

You should change the center property (to move the view) and bounds property (to change it's size) instead. Those properties behave as expected.

Comment: I always favor animating/changing the center property instead of frame.origin. Not just because of the problems mentioned but also because it is much more intuitive.(plus, the frame.origin positions are different for iOS/ Mac OS)

Comment: The thing you have to watch out for when using 'center' as your positioning property is if your frame has an odd pixel width or height. Setting center to integral coordinates in this case will cause your view to go blurry since it won't be pixel-aligned.

Comment: @GregMaletic, on a retina device this isn't an issue, since your coordinates are actually "point" coordinates, and on a retina device a point is 2 screen pixels. Retina devices are able to show sharp images at 1/2 point coordinates.

Answer (score 6):

in my case animation called in viewdidload method. Don't do this. Try on viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that causes the animation to complete immediately, is if the object being animated (UIImageView in my case) is nil.