# How can I transition a UIImage slowly from top to bottom for applying filter to the image?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I want to make it appear as if my image is slowly getting filtered from top to bottom. I am adding two image views. My processed image is in the background and non-processed in the front. I am making the height of non-processed image 0. Here is my code.

```
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 400)
imageView.image = processedImage


let nonProcessedImageView = UIImageView()
nonProcessedImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 400)
nonProcessedImageView.image = nonProcessedImage
view.addSubview(nonProcessedImageView)

UIView.transition(with: nonProcessedImageView,
                  duration: 5.0,
                  animations: {
   nonProcessedImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 500, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 0)
   },
                  completion: {_ in
   })
```

The non processed image does not even appear on top of the processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that changing the `y` coordinate of the frame in the animation block leads to issues when using the UIView.Animate function.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10560577/1619193)

To quote the most essential part:

> You should change the center property (to move the view) and bounds
> property (to change its size) instead. Those properties behave as
> expected.

Since you want to just reduce the height, you don't need to do anything to the `y` coordinate

```
let nonProcessedImageView = UIImageView()

var newImageFrame = imageView.frame

nonProcessedImageView.frame = newImageFrame
nonProcessedImageView.clipsToBounds = true
nonProcessedImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
nonProcessedImageView.image = imageView.image
view.addSubview(nonProcessedImageView)

// I set this to 1 instead of 0 as 0 does not show the image
// for some reason
newImageFrame.size.height = 1

// Update your processed image
imageView.image = processedImage

UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0) {
    nonProcessedImageView.frame = newImageFrame
}
completion: { (isComplete) in
    if isComplete {
        nonProcessedImageView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

This gives some results but as you can see, the animation is not so good because as you reduce the height, the image view's `contentMode` kicks in and gives the seen effect.

[image: UIImageView animate frames swift iOS]

For best results, add the new image view to a UIView and reduce the height of the UIView instead of the UIImageView

```
var newImageFrame = imageView.frame

let containerView = UIView(frame: newImageFrame)
containerView.clipsToBounds = true

let nonProcessedImageView = UIImageView()
nonProcessedImageView.frame = containerView.bounds
nonProcessedImageView.clipsToBounds = true
nonProcessedImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit // same as original
nonProcessedImageView.image = imageView.image

containerView.addSubview(nonProcessedImageView)
view.addSubview(containerView)

newImageFrame.size.height = 1

imageView.image = processedImage

UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0) {
    containerView.frame = newImageFrame
}
completion: { (isComplete) in
    if isComplete {
        containerView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

This should give you what you want:

[image: UIImageView UIView.animate animate image view height swift iOS]

Comment: @VidhiV - please see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks @Shawn Frank - Though it is bottom to top, it serves my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This works for top to bottom transition.

```
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 400)
imageView.image = nonProcessedImage
view.addSubview(imageView)
    
let frontView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 0))
frontView.clipsToBounds = true
view.addSubview(frontView)

let nonProcessedImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 400))
nonProcessedImageView.image = processedImage
nonProcessedImageView.clipsToBounds = true
frontView.addSubview(nonProcessedImageView)
    
UIView.transition(with: frontView, duration: 5, options: [.allowAnimatedContent], animations: {
    frontView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 400)
}, completion: nil)
```